# Issue with presenting and dismissing of AVPlayer Controller

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

So I have an app that takes and records videos to be sent to a server and later viewed.

The sequence of events is as followed
1. Video Recorded
2. Filter or text addedd
3. Sent to server
4. Dismiss avplayer and go back to camera

Everything works but on the fourth step the avplayer never quite dismisses and all I see is this.

[image]

This is an image of all the UI componets on the avplayer controller minus the actual video.

I made sure that I called present and dismiss so there isn't an issue where I used the wrong combination of view controller presentation and dismissal methods. When I get to this screen I have to press the X again to get back to the camera which shouldn't be the case.

```
/// Add the story to firebase
func handleAddToStory() {
    print("Attempting to add to story")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    // hide the color slider so we can return the image of the tapView that contains the text field if they added one
    colorSlider.isHidden = true
    colorSlider.isHidden = false





    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("This is run on the background queue")

        let videoImage = self.imageWithView(inView: self.tapView)


        // Export the video
        self.video?.exportFilterVideo(videoComposition: self.avVideoComposition , completion: { (url) in

            if let videoImage = videoImage {

                let filterVideoAsset = AVAsset(url: url! as URL)

                // Now merge the filtered video with tapView image which will contain the textfield if the user added one
                Merge(config: .standard).overlayVideo(video: filterVideoAsset, overlayImage: videoImage, completion: { (finalVideoUrl) in

                    // Upload to firebase storage
                    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
                    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
                    let uid = User.current.uid
                    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("event_stories").child(self.eventKey).child(uid).child(timeStamp + ".mp4")
                    StorageService.uploadVideo(finalVideoUrl! as URL, at: storageRef) { (downloadUrl) in
                        guard let downloadUrl = downloadUrl else {
                            return
                        }

                        let videoUrlString = downloadUrl.absoluteString
                        print(videoUrlString)
                        // Post to firebase
                        PostService.create(for: self.eventKey, for: videoUrlString)
                    }

                }, progressHandler: { _ in })


            } else {

                let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
                let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
                let uid = User.current.uid
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("event_stories").child(self.eventKey).child(uid).child(timeStamp + ".mp4")
                StorageService.uploadVideo(url! as URL, at: storageRef) { (downloadUrl) in
                    guard let downloadUrl = downloadUrl else {
                        return
                    }

                    let videoUrlString = downloadUrl.absoluteString
                    print(videoUrlString)
                    PostService.create(for: self.eventKey, for: videoUrlString)
                }
                //svprogresshud insert here

            }

        })







        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.videoPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)

        }
    }


}
```

This is the function that handles adding to the server. There are some async task going but those shouldn't tamper with the dismissal of the controller which can be seen at the bottom. Does anyone have any idea why the view controller would still be present?

Below is the snippet of code that presents the aforementioned view controller.

```
  if let event = self.event {
                        let video = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
                        let videoViewController = FilterVideoViewController(video: video)
                        videoViewController.event = event
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss(completion: {
                            self.present(videoViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
                        })

                    }
```

Comment: Can you put `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` top of  `handleAddToStory` function ?

Comment: trying this now

Comment: that doesn't work @Sh_Khan

Comment: comment the below code and see if works or not , if works then main queue is busy embed all below code in a background queue

Comment: @Sh_Khan can you show me an example please im confused

Comment: @Sh_Khan thanks that worked

Comment: added as answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parts

```
video?.exportFilterVideo(videoComposition: avVideoComposition , completion: { (url) in 
   Merge(config: .standard).overlayVideo(video: filterVideoAsset, overlayImage: videoImage, completion: { (finalVideoUrl) in
```

are making the main thread very busy . so you need a background queue like

```
 func handleAddToStory() {
    print("Attempting to add to story")

    // hide the color slider so we can return the image of the tapView that contains the text field if they added one
    colorSlider.isHidden = true
    let videoImage = self.imageWithView(inView: self.tapView)
    colorSlider.isHidden = false
    self.dismiss(animated:false, completion: nil)
    self.videoPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)


    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7 ) {

            video?.exportFilterVideo(videoComposition: avVideoComposition , completion: { (url) in

                if let videoImage = videoImage {

                    let filterVideoAsset = AVAsset(url: url! as URL)

                    // Now merge the filtered video with tapView image which will contain the textfield if the user added one
                    Merge(config: .standard).overlayVideo(video: filterVideoAsset, overlayImage: videoImage, completion: { (finalVideoUrl) in

                        upload(finalVideoUrl! as URL)  

                    }, progressHandler: { _ in })


                } else {

                   upload(url! as URL)

                }

            })

    }


}

func upload(_ url:URL) {

 DispatchQueue.global().async {

    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    let uid = User.current.uid
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("event_stories").child(self.eventKey).child(uid).child(timeStamp + ".mp4")
    StorageService.uploadVideo(url, at: storageRef) { (downloadUrl) in
        guard let downloadUrl = downloadUrl else {
            return
        }

        let videoUrlString = downloadUrl.absoluteString
        print(videoUrlString)
        PostService.create(for: self.eventKey, for: videoUrlString)
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: now im getting this error 
"UIView.layer must be used from main thread only" and this one
"UIView.bounds must be used from main thread only"

Comment: @SJackson5 the best ptactise is once the vc is dismissed it should be deallocated , so you need to hand the below code to say a singleton or something active , i updated the code , but note it's not compiled as i don't know your current vc setup

Comment: I will be trying this now

Comment: im not sure if it is my iphone or what but none of that worked

Comment: it just wont dismiss the viewcontroller regardless of me calling dismiss. I can tell because the deinit is not running

Comment: `self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`?

Comment: "'Upload attempting to execute on non main queue! Please only execute this method on the main queue.'"

Comment: im really lost as to how this started happening out of no where

Comment: do you use any ui things inside the upload

Comment: im going to add the code for the method that i currently have